# Couldn't find my partitions

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I tried to install kali linux 2019 latest version today. I downloaded the i386 image file. Fact is that i wanted a dual boot. I used rufus with DD mode to write the image on a USB. Then i booted the USB & the kali menu arrived, i chose graphical install & all went right till the hard disk selection. I don't find my hard disk partitions. But my hard disk is fine as it's working well with windows 10. I think i downloaded the wrong image because my processor handles x64 base. Is it the reason? Wht should i do? Should i download the 64bit from the kali.org?

Comment: Windows 10 (64-bit Only) _Windows Subsystem for Linux Documentation_ (07/10/2016) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about

Answer (score 1):

Mostly does not depend on architecture. You need to check

1. Whether the disk is encrypted. If it is encrypted check the disk management utility in control panel and decrypt it.(Or any other method provided by the manufacturer)
2. Whether it is a ssd. Debian does not support RAID and RST. If it is ssd then check the bios settings and enable ahci in SATA mode setting. Use [this link](https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci) to check how to change. (Some laptop vendors hide this menu. For acer laptops to unhide option press ctrl+s)

Also try enabling/disabling safeboot

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but the fact is my hard disk drive is not an SSD sheme but a normal HDD. & I use UEFI for Windows & when i chose legacy the kali worked. Please get me a steady solution. But i have set hard disk security, earlier when i installed kali gnome it was not a issue but after today's kali there's a prob.

Comment: Yes thank you for your reply. But the fact is mine is just a HDD, i have enabled password for it during boot time - it's unlocked after i enter it as usual-. Fact is that earlier when i used kali gnome it was fine to detect the disk but today's kali is having an issue. Please help me for further info sir.

Comment: Is that the partition not showing or the entire disk hidden. Use fdisk -l to show disk configuration. Also remember use dd image always and not iso image to create boot pendrive. It is known to cause issues.

Comment: Ok I used DD mode alright. The problem is the option that usually arises during partitioning in Kali : "Guided or ......... "---Is not available.